# Inception V3 Running Stats

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, image-recognition

Has anyone created statistics on how fast and accurate Inception V3 can classify an image based on criteria such as: different models of GPUs/CPUs, input image size, input image ratio, file format, etc?

Example chart I'd hope to see:

```
GPU | CPU | Ratio |   Size   |  Speed  | Accuracy    
 x           1:1     100x100    1000ms     93%
       x     3:4     3k x 4k   40000ms     95%
```

X as in type of GPU/ CPU

Answer (score 1):

Recently, TensorFlow released some scaling benchmarks for convolutional neural networks including Inception at: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/benchmarks

Additionally, we have also released a performance guide to help you optimize your models and systems based on our current best practices: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide and https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models

One important thing to note: depending on your system, you may achieve different results and optimal configurations. It's important to benchmark your own models on your hardware configurations to determine optimal configurations.